# View Automapper's generated sql

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, xdebug

Is there a way to examine the SQL code generated from the following Automapper line of code?

```
         var result = context.Plans.Project().To<PlanViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to see the SQL, for that you need a SQL profiler, or use [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/).


It is possible to see the Expression which is generated by AutoMapper when using the **Map** functionality:

```
Mapper.Engine.CreateMapExpression<Plan, PlanViewModel>().ToString();
```

I don't think there is a method in AutoMapper to view the generated Expression for a Project().To().